# Implementing FCFS CPU Scheduler Algorithm

Tags: c++

I was given an assignment to implement FCFS, SJF, and MLFQ. I am currently attempting to work on FCFS. The algorithm I understand how it is used. The part I am stuck on is creating a C++ program implementing this algorithm. I am given a specific cpu bursts, and I/O times in which i have to implement. I have 8 processes, and each process has multiple cpu bursts and I/O time. Which look like this.

```
P1 {4,24,5,73,3,31,5,27,4,33,6,43,4,64,5,19,2}
P2 {18,31,19,35,11,42,18,43,19,47,18,43,17,51,19,32,10}
P3 {6,18,4,21,7,19,4,16,5,29,7,21,8,22,6,24,5}
P4 {17,42,19,55,20,54,17,52,15,67,12,72,15,66,14}
P5 {5,81,4,82,5,71,3,61,5,62,4,51,3,77,4,61,3,42,5}
P6 {10,35,12,41,14,33,11,32,15,41,13,29,11}
P7 {21,51,23,53,24,61,22,31,21,43,20}
P8 {11,52,14,42,15,31,17,21,16,43,12,31,13,32,15}</code>
```

the order is cpu burst, i/o time, cpu burst, i/o, etc...

Here is how the output should be.

`Current Time: 0`

```
Now Running: P1

Ready Queue:   Process    Burst
                  P2        18
                  P3         6
                  P4        17
                  P5         5
                  P6        10
                  P7        21
                  P8        11
Now In I/O:    Process    Remaining time
                [empty]

Current Time: 4

Now running: P2

Ready queue:   Process    Burst
                P3          6
                P4          17
                P5          5
                P6          10
                P7          21
                P8          11

Now in I/O:    Process    Remaining time
                 P1         24
```

I am thinking that I would have to use a doubly linked list to achieve this. The program is only supposed to output this information only when there is a context-switch. I am not sure exactly where I should be starting. ONly things that come to mind is to create a struct, or class. But I'm not too sure

Comment: yes this is for homework

Comment: would you be able to help me out at all?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist